# Talend: Mapreduce code integration

Tags: talend

i have some questions related to Talend:

1. is it possible to include mapreduce code into Talend and execute from it?
2. when we execute after setting up componenets, will Talend convert it to mapreduce job?

Answer (score 3):

1) You need to have Talend Enterprise Edition for BigData for your first answer.Their talend includes custom code components where you can write your own mapper and reducer code.

2) Yes talend convert it to MapReduce code but only for following components Hive,Pig,Sqoop,HBase.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to both questions are: yes!

[This video](https://help.talend.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=18175254) shows you how they design the job with the tool.

You have to use the software called: `Talend Open Studio for Big Data` 
Last release is: v5.3.1

The documentation is here:

- [Getting started](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataGettingStartedGuide53EN/1.2+Functional+architecture+of+Talend+Big+Data+solutions)
- [Component Reference](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide53EN/Home)

Comment: I think it should be pointed out that MapReduce code can be generated only in the premium version of Talend Open Studio for Big Data. On the free version, you can draw Pig/Hive jobs, btw.